# How can I change the color of an mdiTab that already has a style assigned to it? (Infragistics)

Tags: styles, infragistics, mdi

I want to make the color of  a tab change on a certain event. The ISL file for the project contains the following:

```
<styleLibrary>
  <styleSets defaultStyleSet="Default">
    <styleSet name="Default" viewStyle="Standard">
      ...
      <styles>
        ...
        <style role="TabItem">
          <states>
            <state name="Normal">
              <resources>
                <name>Header</name>
              </resources>
            </state>

            <state name="HotTracked">
              <resources>
                <name>HeaderHotTrack</name>
              </resources>
            </state>

            <state name="Active">
              <resources>
                <name>HeaderActive</name>
              </resources>
            </state>
            ...
          </states>
        </style>
      </styles>
    </styleSet>
  <resources>
    ...
    <resource name="Header" backColor="White" foreColor="Black" backColor2="255, 152, 53" backGradientStyle="Vertical" />

    <resource name="HeaderActive" backColor="255, 237,175" foreColor="Black" backColor2="255, 127, 0" backGradientStyle="Vertical" />

    <resource name="HeaderHotTrack" backColor="25, 237, 175" foreColor="White" backColor2="255,127, 0" backGradientStyle="Vertical" />

    <resource name="HeaderHasUpdates" backColor="Green" foreColor="Black" backColor2="White" backGradientStyle="Vertical" />
    ...
  </resources>
</styleLibrary>
```

When the program begins, it is loaded with:

Infragistics.Win.AppStyling.StyleManager.Load()

When the tab is selected, the tab is colored as the resource named "HeaderActive". At a certain trigger, I want it to be switched to the resource named "HeaderHasUpdates." What I currently have which isn't working is this (where mdiTab is an Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabbedMdi.MdiTab):

mdiTab.Settings.TabAppearance.StyleResourceName = "HeaderHasUpdates"

If I remove all of the resources except the "HeaderHasUpdates" one, the forecolor actually does change, which makes me think there's another place where the colors are being set and at that spot, the foreColor isn't being set. I'm just unfamiliar with the precedence of color styles.

So what can I do to change the style?

-- EDIT 4/17/2012 --

For the record, the fix added in the following under <styleSet> and above <styles>:

```
<componentStyles>
  <componentStyle name="UltraTabbedMdiManager" resolutionOrder="ControlThenApplication">
    <properties>
      <property> name="ViewStyle" colorCategory="{Default}">Office2003</property>
    </properties>
  </componentStyle>
</componentStyles>
```

Just in case you didn't want to use the AppStylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never done that so this need to be tested, however I think you could try to define in your ISL file two StyleSet. (Style Explorer-> Add)

In the first you set your default style, in the second you define only the Style for the TabHeader.
When you need the different style, just set the StyleSetName to the second StyleSet available in your ISL file. Don't know if some kind of refresh will be needed.

Also if you want to override the settings from appstylist with appearances defined at design time, you would need to check the **ResolutionOrder** in AppStylist 
Go to `"Component Role Settings->Infragistics Components->UltraTabControl->ResolutionOrder"`
The ResolutionOrder is, by default, set to `ApplicationThenControl` which 
means that the AppStyling property values take precedence over any control 
settings for the corresponding appearance properties. In your case, you 
should change that to `ControlThenApplication` so the properties set on 
the control will take precedence.

Comment: Well this is interesting: I changed the ResolutionOrder. It does allow me to set the tab color either using "Settings.TabAppearance.BackColor" or "Settings.TabAppearance.StyleResourceName". However, the new colors only show up when I have a different tab selected.

Comment: there is an ActiveTabAppearance in addition to the TabAppearance and this would be used when the tab is selected.